# BLE value_change

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
private async void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            // BT_Code: An Indicate or Notify reported that the value has changed.
            // Display the new value with a timestamp.
            var newValue = FormatValueByPresentation(args.CharacteristicValue, presentationFormat);
            var message = $"Value at {DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss}: {newValue}";
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () => CharacteristicLatestValue.Text = message);
        }
```

This is a setup for value change. ^

```
 private async void CharacteristicReadButton_Click()
        {
             // BT_Code: Read the actual value from the device by using Uncached.
            GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                string formattedResult = FormatValueByPresentation(result.Value, presentationFormat);

                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read result: {formattedResult}", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read failed: {result.Status}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }     


        }
```

This is a setup for reading value. So when I click the "read" button. It captures the data at that moment of time. But I want this data to be refresh whenever the value change so I subscribed to value change. **The problem now is, after I click subscribe, all it says is "unknown format". So I need to figure out how to change my format to read my rfduino value.**

"read" button pressed:
[image]

subscribe" button pressed[image]

"subscribe" button pressed"

Comment: Do you test this using the [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE) sample? Could you tell me the steps how can I reproduce this issue? Could you provide a simple reproducible sample?

Comment: meaning ? what you intend to do with the bluetoothLE sample ?

Comment: Just want to know how to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a unknown format, it is difficult to get some useful out of it.
To read your raw data in Hex String format You have to change the last line in Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs, **FormatValueByPresentation(IBuffer buffer, GattPresentationFormat format)** :
from

```
 return "Unknown format";
```

to:

```
return "Unknown format: " + BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

or:

```
var result = data.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) => s + i.ToString());//add using System.Linq
         return "Unknown format: " + result;
```

Comment: It did changed something. But it did not display the data I need. My rfduino value is in char. Does it matter ?

Comment: If your value was char, it would not return Unknown format.

Comment: but it did returned though. You want to take a look at my arduino code ?

Comment: No, just tell me what you send in arduino and what you receive in  your app.

Comment: I send a char character, in my case is angle. What I receive in my serial monitor is the angle value.

Comment: It didnt display the angle. It just shows a bunch of numbers o.o

Comment: is there a problem with my {newValue} ? The first code in this post. Is it I must set newValue to char ?

Comment: If the read button shows you the correct value then this value is not in the notification payload( args.CharacteristicValue) but just a notification or indication there is something to read. Try to invoke the read button click in Characteristic_ValueChanged.

Comment: How do I do that ? I thought of that too but I'm not sure how to invoke it

Comment: that's easy just copy all the lines from CharacteristicReadButton_Click() and add it to characristic_ValueChanged

Comment: Okay. I will try and get back to you

Comment: Do I need to edit any other thing? I just copy and paste ?

Comment: Do you have Teamviewer ? We can share screen and you can take a look at my coding on my arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well; it looks like the data 'format' is null. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the BLE device. I don't know - I'm not a BLE expert. It is just an inexpensive device used to create a wireless link to a serial port. Any 8-bit ASCII characters received on the serial port are sent to the subscribed client as-is.

I've added the following at the end of the FormatValueByPresentation() function:

```
    try
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return "(error: Invalid UTF-8 string)";
    }
```

... instead of:

```
 return "Unknown format";
```

This then properly formats the data from the serial device. Hope this helps!!